# htaccess url rewrite if file doesn't exist *OR* specific directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess rewrite rule that rewrites if the file requested doesn't exist, but I would also like this rule to ignore this rule if the request falls within a specific directory. I am unsure how to do this however.

My current rewrite rule is this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How would you modify to ignore a specific directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldername
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Should do the trick